# How to delete Github's wiki homepage?

Tags: github

Today I put my password to Github's wiki `Home` page. Then, I know it's a mistake.

How to remove this page? (I can remove child page, but I don't know how to delete wiki `Home` page)

Comment: Change your password.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying.  The wiki is a separate repository and you can pull it down, delete the file, and check in as normal.  But your password is compromised and you should change it anyway.

Comment: Rename your page to something else other than "Home" and save it, now again try seeing it you will find delete button

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The wiki is simply a separate git repository, so you can check it out and remove files the same way you would with anything else.  Simply apply `.wiki` to the name (so if your repository is named `my_repo`, clone `my_repo.wiki.git` instead of `my_repo.git`) and clone to do this.

However, that said, you should definitely change your password anyway; it is compromised.

[Github provides instructions to permanently purge a repository of a file here](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/) but it is my opinion that it's not worth bothering, given that the password should never be used again now that you have exposed it.  You simply cannot know who has already pulled down the information and seen it (and numerous bad actors run scripts regularly on Github specifically to harvest credentials mistakenly committed).

Comment: _First_ step: Change your password immediately. The one you accidentally published is now compromised.

Comment: @Chris Yeah, I agree... my response was edited though.

Comment: Strange approach.

Answer (score 90):

I faced the same issue.

I was not able to Delete Wiki's "Home" page as Delete Button was not appearing for "Home" page when I go in Edit Mode.

To Delete the Wiki's "Home" page, do the following Steps:

1. Rename "Home" to anything else. It seems that GitHub considers
   "Home" to be the default page and hence the "Delete" button disappears.
2. Click on "Edit Page". Or Navigate to Edit Mode
3. And now you can see the "Delete" button.
4. Delete the page and you are Done.

Comment: I dont know why this was downvoted. It worked fine for me.

Comment: This is much easier than the accepted answer, thanks!

Comment: @nahtnam maybe because, in a way, someone with access to the wiki repo can see the git log, then see the password. Btw, as I wrote this comment, deleting home page will create this weird "New Page" when not logged in.

Comment: Now the question is how do you delete the repo altogether so you get the "Welcome to the x-project wiki!" message back?

Comment: this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on "Edit Page".
2. Now you can see the "Delete" button to top right in red color
3. Click on that delete button.
4. Be careful, it will not ask yes/no confirmation

Comment: No, you don't see the "Delete" button for the "Home" page. (That's why he wrote he can remove other pages, but not "Home".)

Comment: @Sz. did you noticed it: `"Delete" button to the top right in red color`

Comment: Wow, which GitHub are you using? For the one everyone else seems to, I'm afraid I can only repeat the point of the OP (and my earlier comment), and what you've been continuing to ignore (which is equivalent to saying that all the other answers & commenters have been experiencing an alternate reality, right?): the entire issue is about the `Home` page **_only_**. There's no such thing as a red "Delete" button for **_that one_** (at least in "my" GitHub, where I've just double-checked, again). You only have a "Delete" button for **_all the other_** pages.

Comment: Hmm, do you, perhaps, happen to have a setup, where a page is called "Home", but is not in fact the real dedicated start (`Home`) page of your GH wiki? I'm not sure right now, off the top of my head, what actually qualifies as a "real" Home page of a GH wiki, but in a vanilla, default setup, the issue described by the OP (and everyone else on this page) still seems to apply.